# Postgresql12 db pretty size difference

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

We recently moved from a PG12.7 running on Kubernetes to PG12.14 on a VM. Post migration, we checked all the rowcount and it is there in new db. But when I used pg_pretty_size, the difference of db size is huge in both dbs.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('mydb'));
```

What might be causing this? I havent knowingly set any compression in the new DB running on VM.

Comment: define huge please

Comment: size in new db is approx 1GB and in old DB it is 4GB @nbk

Comment: like any other databse, tires postgres to optimize, so that it adds information to the dataqbase, over time and so a new database is natureally , smaller, i hought  ou ment that it has increased in size

Answer (score 0):

A database that is in use will tend to accumulate sub optimal storage.
Rows and tables grow and shrink and the space that gets freed doesn't get reclaimed since it is

1. likely that it will be reused anyway
2. it is spread in small chunks throughout the files, so it is not trivial to reclaim it.

When you set up a new database, depending on how exactly you do it, it is likely that all tables and there rows are stored in a clean and orderly way, without any extra space, so the result are database files of smaller size.

Kind of like defragmenting databases back in the days.
Or for the younger kids: If you have your cloths on a big pile in your room and then move to a new apartment and in the process put away the cloths in a neat way you might actually save some space.